# Why does this not work? (VBA)

Tags: vba

I appreciate this is very basic, but I've tried debugging and I can't figure out why 'Number1' does not get a number assigned to it once the 4th line runs. It stays as zero. Currently when I run all the cells get marked as green.

```
Sub Colour()

    Dim Number1 As Long

    For i = 17 To 32

        Number1 = Cells(i, 12).Value

        If Number1 < Cells(i, 6).Value And Number1 > Cells(i, 5).Value Then

        Cells(i, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    Else

        Cells(i, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    End If

        Next i


    End Sub
```

Comment: What is in cell L17 of the active sheet?  Also, what is in E17 and F17?  (I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you will say something like `0.21`, `0.30` and `0.50`, to which we will reply "`Long` is an integer numeric type, so `0.21` will be rounded to `0`".)

Comment: i copy your code and cheked it and it works fine if given condition is true. Fills cell with color red. so you should probably work on your if statements id you don't see the outcome you expect. İf you provide date we can help further.